Docker Compose, Rails 6, and Webpack Development Server for Development Environment
I am attempting to use webpack-dev-server with my Rails 6 application, and using the configuration below, I am getting some odd behavior.
When I change an asset file, the webpack container does run, emits a manifest.js file to /public/packs, but none of the asset files, as the log seems to indicate it should:
js/application-d7d222001d0bf9a0d1c1.js   2.12 MiB          application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
js/application-d7d222001d0bf9a0d1c1.js.map   2.14 MiB          application  [emitted] [dev]        application
js/vendors~actioncable-d71b90a0f9902ec55bfa.chunk.js   34.4 KiB  vendors~actioncable  [immutable]            vendors~actioncable
js/vendors~actioncable-d71b90a0f9902ec55bfa.chunk.js.map   26.9 KiB  vendors~actioncable  [dev]                  vendors~actioncable
manifest.json  554 bytes                       [emitted]       

The rails container does emit manifest.js and the asset files to /public/packs after a change in the non-hot-load fashion (it requires a page reload, and initiates webpacking after the request.
The following are the relevant files:

/config/webpacker.yml

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  additional_paths: []

  cache_manifest: false

  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    port: 3035

    # For `./bin/webpack-dev-server`
    host: localhost
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # # For Docker compose (doesn't work yet)
    # host: webpack
    # public: webpack:3035
    # hmr: true

    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


/docker-compose.yml

version: '3.1'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: application_x_postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  rails:
    container_name: application_x_rails
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - webpack
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpack
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    network_mode: host
  webpack:
    container_name: application_x_webpack
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=development
    command: /app/bin/webpack-dev-server
    ports:
      - 3035:3035
    network_mode: host


/docker/rails.Dockerfile

FROM timbru31/ruby-node:3.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential apt-utils libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR /app

RUN gem install bundler

COPY Gemfile* ./

RUN bundle install

ADD . /docker/app

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]

I don't know why I need the network_type: host setting on the rails container, but it is necessary to allow the rails container to communicate with the postgres container, with this current setup.
Obviously, I am missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Noticed in the docker-compose.yml for the webpack container it has the command as command: /app/bin/webpack-dev-server, I reckon it should be command: ./app/bin/webpack-dev-server

@djmonki Thank you, but that's not it. webpack-dev-server runs when an asset file is changed, and it emits the manifest.js file.
If the command were bad, Docker Compose would not even compile.

not much time on the clock so heres a couple stabs

set the network mode to bridge and configure a network eg:
networks:
     myNetwork:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
         config:
           - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24


run the webpack build server from the host rather than in the container, you only really wanted to sync the files after compilation, the container just needs to statically host the files

Use docker inspect to check that the right volumes are mounted.


